# Visual Studio GIT push certification error

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

I trying to push my local changes to GIT repository. I am getting following error when pushing.

```
Pushing ****
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error. 
unable to access 'https://***.visualstudio.com/****/_git/***/': 
SSL  certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Pushing to https://****.visualstudio.com/****/_git/****
```

I am able to connect to repo through the browser and even through the visual studio.
I tried resolved.d the following article too. But couldn't 
[Certificate copy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/)

Answer (score 0):

I just found one possible cause for this error, apparently you must install git on its own on your computer in addition to the visual studio extension. https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.33.1.windows.1

I realized by following the certificate path and it not existing. By installing git, the certificate was created and I was able to push to my repository from visual studio.

Disabling ssl certificate checks is also not a good solution as it introduces security holes. And I couldn't run the command to do so anyway, since git commands where not installed on my machine either.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-816521128.html)

```
Problem

The following is seen on the command line when pushing or pulling:

SSL Certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
Cause

This error occurs when a self-signed certificate cannot be verified. 
Workaround

Tell git to not perform the validation of the certificate using the global option:

git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: Where exactly does this command must be executed?